# How can I save a video in PhoneGap using captureVideo?

Tags: cordova

Capturing and saving an image in PhoneGap is very easy and straight-forward using the options in captureImage(), but captureVideo only has 3 options (none of which are supported) and they aren't related to saving the video.

Has anyone had any luck doing this using the File object after the video is captured?

Answer (score 0):

Get more info: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideo

If you would using captureVideo, your video is saved automatically and to access it try this:

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    alert(mediaFiles[0].fullPath);       
}
```

Note: put null in the option parameter or limit:1

Full Example:

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    alert(mediaFiles[0].fullPath);       
}

function captureError(error) {
    alert('An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code);
}

function captureVideo() {
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, null);
}
```

Comment: The file path for the Video is saved, not the video itself.